# Connected region detection (blob detection) in black and white UIImage

Tags: ios, algorithm, image-processing, uiimage, graph-algorithm

How would I do connected region detection in an iOS app? I have a black and white UIImage (binary image) and need to find the locations and bounding box size of all connected regions in that image. OpenCV is not an option for this project but any other 3rd party libraries are.

Comment: You could just implement your own [connected component labeling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). One-pass and two-pass versions are very easy to understand and implement. Or just google to find some ready-to-use implementation. Once you have each component, finding bounsing boxes is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but here it is. You can use the Union-find algorithm to label the connected components. Here are a [C and Java implementation](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/).